# Функция должна открывать разные widget в зависимости от того, что выбрал

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

Что у меня есть:

в конструкторе:

```
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openCatClicked()));
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openDogClicked()));
```

Моя функция

```
void Widget::openClicked()
{
    if( mTableModel->openComp(CAT) == true)
    {
        mCatWidget = new CatWidget();
        mCatWidget->show();
    }
    else if (mTableModel->openComp(DOG) == false)
    {
        mDogWidget = new DogWidget();
        mDogWidget->show();
    }
}
```

В моделе у меня функция:

```
bool TableModel::openComponent(Type type)
{
    if( type  == CAT )
    {
        return true;
    }

    if( type == DOG )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Но у меня всегда открываются оба виджета. Нужна ваша помощь!

**UPD:**

```
bool Model::openComp(Type type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case 0:
        return Cat;
    case 1:
        return DOG;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**UPD2:**

```
void Widget::openClicked()
{
    if( mTableModel->openComp(CAT) == true)
    {
        mCatWidget = new CatWidget();
        mCatWidget->show();
    }
    else  if (mTableModel->openComp(DOG) == false)
    {
        mDogWidget = new DogWidget();
        mDogWidget->show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы к одному action цепляете 2 слота:

```
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openCatClicked()));
connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openDogClicked()));
```

Т.е. Вы на сигнал `triggered` одного `openAction` повесили и `openCatClicked`, и `openDogClicked`. Вот Вам оба диалога и показываются.

Comment: я  это уже исправила. я  одну вместо двух функций  написала. connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openClicked()));

Comment: UPD2 моя функция. можете  хотя бы вы  написать в какой строке у меня  лажа

Comment: А сейчас у меня только собака открывается всегда. А мне  нужно чтобы  открывалось  то что я  выберу.

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, Ваша функция `openComp` и на `CAT` и на `DOG` возращает `true` (при условии, что CAT & DOG > 0). У Вас какая-то кривая функция `openClicked`. Сделайте как у Вас изначально написано: `openCatClicked` и `openDogClicked`, и в них создавайте соответствующие диалоги.

Comment: а как мне в конект передавать их?

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, у Вас должно быть 2 action (кнопки, или чего у Вас там), к каждому action подсоединяйте свой слот и всё.

Comment: а нет. у меня  одна кнопка и когда я  ее выбираю  появляется  еще подменю и я там выбираю или собака или кот

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, ну так на каждое подменю должен быть свой action. Один на собаку, один на кота.

Comment: я извеняють. на тупила. у меня одна кнопка. Но мне нужно: у меня есть таблица и в  этой таблице есть  два названия собака и кот. и если я  нажимаю  на кот то мне  должен открыться  виджет с котом. все про него. а если на собаку то открыться виджет на собаку. поэтому я и туплю не  знаю как отличать их

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, тогда Ваш вопрос переворачивается с ног на голову и всё нужно делать по другому, видимо. Удаляйте тогда этот вопрос и создавайте новый, где приводите всю релевантную информацию. Иначе Вам никто не поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам наверное нужно делать так: (хотя ваши намерения не очень понятны):

```
bool Model::openComp(Type type)
{
   return type == CAT;
}
void Widget::openClicked(Type t)
{
  if( mTableModel->openComp(t) == true)
  {
     mCatWidget = new CatWidget();
     mCatWidget->show();
  }
  else  
  {
     mDogWidget = new DogWidget();
     mDogWidget->show();
  }
}
```

Может быть, что я неверно понимаю что вы пытаетесь делать...

Comment: а  тут правильно я  передаю? connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openClicked(Type type)));

Comment: а то пишет: QObject::connect: No such slot Widget::openClicked(Type type) in ..\..\Application\Widget.cpp:81

Comment: Во первых я не в курсе  в каком классе вы  определяете слот,  во вторых т вы уже должны вызвать функцию.      connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openCatClicked(CAT)));

Comment: я  это вызываю в  главном виджете в конструкторе

Comment: тоже самое: QObject::connect: No such slot TeacherWidget::openClicked(CAT) in ..\..\Application\Widget.cpp:81

Comment: и у меня  одна функция openClicked. А вы почему то написали : openCatClicked(CAT))